# How to return extended object with some of the base object's values pre-filled?

Tags: typescript

I have a base interface and another interface extends it. I'm trying to write a function, that will get some arguments from the base interface and some will be prefilled. If there are any new properties that do not exist in the base interface, it is also accepted as arguments since they can't be pre-filled.

```typescript
interface Foo {
  prop: number;
  hidden: number;
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
  prop: 1;
  hidden: 2;
  newProp: string;
}

const createThing = <T extends Foo>({
  prop,
  ...rest
}: Omit<T, keyof Foo> & Pick<T, 'prop'>): T => {
  return {
    prop,
    hidden: 3, // <-- I want this prefilled, but it must be 2, not 3.
    ...rest,
  }; /* if I write `as T`, it works, but it allows me to pass 3 to the 
        `hidden` property, which will be wrong. */
  
  /* but this whole return complains, that T could be instantiated with
     a different subtype of constraint 'Foo'. */
};

const thing = createThing<Bar>({ prop: 1, newProp: 'foo' });
thing.hidden === 2; /* this will be false, because I returned 3 
                       from the createThing function. */
```

What is the proper way to achieve this?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIAOU6RAXMiAK4C2ARtANz6EAWwAJpxCJTQ2a4AvrlyhIsRCgBCcKMggAPSCE4BnNJhysCJMpQCMLQsg7delAEwnCICAHcACqQrJ1YKKADmLUbgR0EA9kBCgIOEgAFQ4Qb2QAXmQAHijFFV4NLXQAPgAKbGJXABpkADoK8JDhSgB5WmAwVNKAawgAT3QYbJzkADJkJ2AEFubkAHJ9InGcgEpKNITevFNwsGooEB1TUyni3R3zHj5kAGZSgHoLlIBaG+QASWROLGo1aA84NWQwDk1gTRwIroegAGwgtFKjAQcGo6hQAAM5FAEcgGt42GB0qpONlkA5GmwfmxEUdeKipj8sIxkF92lQ6IwFOgFAj7AA3aAIsoHUwVMpVMD7UzCWwEK7IejULG-AH4tjocHINYbLaBWhEUFwUDqUq-SLINKBaig3E0nVgL5gYCRCC4gm-WnPYAwGDQXhY9TUehgdpEFBdUJBDxQbXgCYYdDjHmisSBYIy2LxJJhCLRJPJZH5QpTIylezOVyUcYwTDjZDCWYsWVxMpkrYJRvIKzICWyzQE0GgyUoeCg+FQiAwuEoJ4qzZ2s7IGCkWjElCp20xHzTt4Ia1BHlAA)

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve here. It seems like a [discriminating union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) may be what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand this, your `createThing<T>` method can accept any properties of T (`Partial<T>`) and it requires the inclusion of any new properties were not part of Foo (`Omit<T, keyof Foo>`). That is,

```
type Props<T extends Foo> = Partial<T> & Omit<T, keyof Foo>;
```

Where things get trickier is when T has the same property name as in Foo, but with a more specific type. ie. `hidden` must be `2`, not just any `number`.  You could require that these properties be included in Props, but you've said that you want them pre-filled.

I've written this where you have a separate set of defaults for each thing interface, and you pass those in to createThing.  Otherwise how would it know what is and isn't an appropriate default?

If I understand this correctly, the extra properties don't need defaults, but any of the Foo interface properties need a default if they are made more specific.  Here I am using a mapped type to figure out which properties you need.

```
type NarrowedKeys<T extends Foo> = {
    // there's probably a cleaner way to write this
    [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof Foo ? Foo[K] extends T[K] ? never : K : never
}[keyof T];

type NarrowedDefaults<T extends Foo> = Pick<T, NarrowedKeys<T>>
```

At this point, I still get the `'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Foo'` message, but I'm content to hush it with `as T` because I cannot pass the invalid value of hidden in either `NarrowedDefaults<Bar>` or `Props<Bar>`.

```
const fooDefaults: Foo = {
    prop: 1,
    hidden: 5,
}

const createThing = <T extends Foo>(tDefaults: NarrowedDefaults<T>) => (props: Props<T>): T => {
    return {
        ...fooDefaults,
        ...tDefaults,
        ...props,
    } as T;
};

const createBar = createThing<Bar>({
    prop: 1,
    hidden: 2,
});
const thing = createBar({prop: 1, newProp: 'foo'});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIAOU6RAXMiAK4C2ARtANz6EAWwAJpxCJTQ2a4AvrlyhIsRCgBCcKMggAPSCE4BnNJhysCJMpQCMLQsg7delAEwnCICAHcACqQrJ1YKKADmLUbjAATyIUADl5UgcITgBpCED1AB4AFUUVXg0tdAA%20ZABeHVMAeiLkMDZoCAByTX16OHoAG0DkOGQERog4ewUHOBawLAcvSDKOdV1kAG0Y5FBkAGt49BhkZIBdSlnlVUylwJWs5AB%20LJn1tN3NZPOTqggAN2hkLZf7p6gRKf3DjZYA4JhCLoKKcAAiEHg1EaYCSqR2GU0GBy%20WQTmACAWKQANMhwlBItE4gkUtlsmIEOgQB5kDBMBCoTD1JRkai8KZ9G5DNjJuYeHxkABWHnCf5BEJo1xwy6IrK5ApOeRgYBwRqk5AAMmQAHlaMAwDjFstVsjsv9KdSwO0oF1IMkOCBvKiUjK1EjMNkABRgBlwaGwyj4wngyF%20pmkgCU%20Vyns5zMlZDh2QjlFSeVy7MINrA1CgIEKpkIADoS3T0L7-eoeYXiyWfaHK9Wa8gS0W402CMJWtcROaqTSEDa4JA5AoCoPbRB7T5EqOvZm9K4jB2zFx%20dYRRGWBaaeUfKiJ8OIKPPdhOcv7s4l8gqmWqsIt0A)

Comment: Although I wanted something a bit different (I don't wanted to expose the default prefilled props to the function parameters), but you are correct. There is no other way of doing it if it does not know that the extended interface will have the same prop. I'm marking this as resolved.

EDIT: thank you!